# Data from array in VueJS not populating on frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I am trying to get an array of data called "ROOMS" to populate into a table on my site. I have to admit I have not done this in over 18 months so I feel like I am missing something very simple. The data is as follows

- ID
- ROOM NAME
- ROOM DESCRIPTION

This is my frontend code

```
                          <tr  v-for="(getRoom, index) in GetRooms" :key="index" :value="room" :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-gray-50'">
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              <div class="flex items-center">
                                <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                  <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="#" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-4">
                                  <div class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900">
                                    {{ room.name }}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
```

Obviously I need to pull in the description and so on but thats the core code. My JS is as follows

```
export default {
  components: {
    Dialog,
    DialogOverlay,
    DialogTitle,
    TransitionChild,
    TransitionRoot,
    CheckIcon,
    XIcon,
  },
  props: ['roomlist'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      chatRooms: [],
      currentRoom: [],
      messages: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closePanel() {
      this.open = false
    },
    getRooms() {
      axios.get('/chat/rooms')
      .then( response => {
        this.chatRooms = response.data;
        this.setRoom ( response.data[0] );
      })
      .catch ( error => {
        console.log ( error );
      })
    },
    setRoom ( room ){
      this.currentRoom = room;
      this.getMessages();
    },
    getMessages(){
      axios.get('/chat/room/' + this.currentRoom.id + '/messages')
      .them( response => {
        this.messages = response.data;
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getRooms();
  },
  setup() {
    const open = ref(true)

    return {
      open,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Can someone just point out what I screwed up. I know its something simple. I always over complicate things.

Comment: `GetRooms` is not available in your script, and I believe based on your need, you need to use `chatRooms` variable or `currentRoom`

Comment: @RiyazKhan Can you make this an answer - you got it - thank you for finding my silly screwup!!!

Comment: `getRooms` method is not returning any data as such nothing is rendered. `getRooms` is used in your loop -> change it to a variable that has the data. HOWEVER, `getRooms` has no trigger and therefore no data will be loaded. therefore, you will need to add an `on/Mounted` event to trigger it or another event

Answer (score 1):

As I checked your code, I found that `GetRooms` is not available in your script, and I believe based on your need, you need to use `chatRooms` variable or `currentRoom`